# SpringBoot issue while migrating from log4j to lof4j2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

**BEFORE(Works Fine)**

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/spring-boot-mqtt.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%-5p] [%t] [%c{1}] - %m%n
```

and maven dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**AFTER(Doesn't Work)**

**log4j2.properties**

```
name = PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = file

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = ROLLING
appender.file.append = true
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/spring-boot-mqtt.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%-5p] [%t][%c{2}] - %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = file
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = ROLLING
```

and my maven dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i use the same configuration for `log4j2` in a standalone java application, it works fine. But in `spring-boot` application, a file is generated but it stays empty. I see same defualt log in console. Also `layout.pattern` in properties doesn't seem to affect anything.

**NOTE** : Using Slf4j

Answer (score 1):

Regarding writing to files you should check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html):

> By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console and will not
>   write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
>   console output you need to set a logging.file or logging.path property
>   (for example in your application.properties).

Comment: But if i use `log4j1.x`, i have to do nothing like that. What is the difference here? I only changed the properties file and dependencies to log4j2, rest is same as before.

Comment: Update application.properties as suggested.

Comment: I will do that if i need to generate the log somewhere else rather than console. But what if i want the log to be generated at the location mentioned in the `log4j2.properties` file?